# Аннотация @WebServlet и аннотация @Path

Tags: java, java-ee

Один вопрос по этому коду: Корректно ли использовать `@WebServlet` вместе с `@Path`?

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/login",name = "LoggerServlet")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5763766570953298418L;

@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

@Context
HttpServletResponse response;

@Path("/logger/{id}")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public void login (User user, @PathParam("id")long id) throws ConnectionFailed, CouponSystemException, ServletException,InvalidLogin,IOException, UserNotFound {

    LoginAuthentication validator = new LoginAuthentication();
    Response resp = validator.validate(user);

    int status  = resp.getStatus();   

          if(status == 200){
      service(request, response);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, нет. Аннотация `Path` - это часть `JAX-RS`, в то время как `WebServlet` - это, собственно, сервлеты.
Разница в том, что для работы с сервлетом необходимо наследовать `HttpServlet` и оверрайдить методы `doGet(httpRequest, httpResponse)`, `doPost(...)`, те из них, которые нужны. Если HTTP метод не заоверрайден, то будет возвращена ошибка из разряда 'server does not support this http method'.

Тем временем, `JAX-RS` - это рест веб сервисы. Для работы рест веб сервиса в javaEE необходим один и только один наследник `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` с заполненной аннотацией `ApplicationPath` и для каждого сервиса класс с аннотацией `Path`, который может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@Path("/users")
public class UsersEndpoint {

  @Inject
  private List<User> users;

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public User getUser(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return users.get(id);
  }
}
```

`JAX-RS` - технология более высокого уровня абстракции, нежели сервлеты. Зачастую ее достаточно, но иногда приходится использовать именно сервлеты.